# Ubuntu 14.10 disconnects from wifi after waking up from suspension

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 14.10 LTS. When I suspend my laptop and wake it up later from sleep, or when I close my laptop lid and open it later on, or when I want to change my network, I loose wifi connection and it would never work until I restart. This bugs me because I have programs open, and when I close my laptop and go to a different place, Ubuntu can't connect to wifi unless I restart (which means closing all programs).

Do you have any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: related http://askubuntu.com/questions/452826/wireless-networking-not-working-after-resume-in-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same issue. Might be a bug. Quick workaround is to run

```
sudo killall NetworkManager
```

from the command line. It will respawn quickly and connect.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1354924

P.S. 14.10 is not LTS.